# wikitude Augmented Reality Application using Augmented Reality

Tags: cordova, augmented-reality, wikitude

I am trying to create a location base augmented reality application using wikitude phonegap plugin,I need to implement something similar to the 3_PointOfInterest_1_PoiAtLocation application which is inside the wikitude-sdk-samples-master ,

I have use js,css,and jquery folders which are provided withwikitude-sdk-samples-master bundle. But it doesn't work for me,If anybody knows a good reference for building location base augmented reality application using wikitude plugin please give me the link .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikitude examples for PhoneGap should give you a good introduction how the SDK works in combination with PhoneGap.
You basically need to add the Plugin to your existing project, create a new folder inside your platform www folder that contains your Architect World (html/js/css) and then load the Architect World using the Wikitude Plugin.

You can also use Safari Web Inspector, maybe you get some more information about whats going wrong in your application.

Here is a link for the [Wikitude PhoneGap documentation](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/phonegap).